# Is there a difference in a front and rear ignition coil? Can they be replaced with a generic ignition coil?

Tags: motorcycle, ignition-coil

I have an 04' Suzuki Intruder VL1500 LC. Recently replaced the ignition coils with some aftermarket. Issue I'm having is the "ignition" fuse keeps blowing. Is there a difference in front/rear ignition coils, can either be replaced with a generic brand or do I just have a/both bad coils?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!